# Why is increment on returned value on righthand side of return statement not evaluated?

Tags: java, return, increment

I'd like to know why a postfix increment on a value being returned in a return statement is not evaluated if the increment occurs on the righthand side of the return statement.

I know that the value returned should be the pre-increment value, but assuming a class-level variable, the increment should still show up in the variable itself.

Here is my example.

---

public class ReturnDemo {

```
static int val=1;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(getVal());
    System.out.println(val);


}
public static int getVal()
{
    return(val=(val++));
}
```

}

---

I would have expected this to print out
1
2
but it actually printed out 
1
1

If you do the same thing without the assign, it increments correctly.

This, for example:

---

public class ReturnDemo {

```
static int val=1;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(getVal());
    System.out.println(val);


}
public static int getVal()
{
    return(val++);
}
```

}

---

Returns 
1
2 
(It gets val at 1 then increments the variable val to 2.)

Why is it that there is a line drawn in the sand at evaluating the postfix increment within a return statement if it's on the righthand side of an assignment, but that same line is not applied to postfix increments that are not part of an assignment statement?

Comment: The short answer is that it >>is<< incremented, but the incremented value is then thrown away.  For more details, please refer to the linked Question and its Answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return is a red herring. The problem is `val=(val++)`, which is Just Plain Ugly and Bad Practice.

`val++` is post-increment. In other words, this subexpression returns the previous value of `val`, then increments the variable.

So you are telling the compiler you want to obtain the previous value of `val` (1), then increment it (2), then assign that previous value to `val` -- setting it back to 1 again. The program is doing exactly what you told it to do.

You're trying too hard. If you want to return the value of `val` after it has been incremented, you can use `return ++val;`. If you want to increment `val` but return the *previous* value, use `return val++;`.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe that between this and the prior thread provided by Stephen, I understand what is happening. 
I'd interpreted i=i++; as having 2 steps:
1.   (i from LHS)=(i from RHS);
2.   (i from RHS)++;

When it is in 3 steps, such that
i=i++; translates to: 
1.  temp=(i from RHS);
2.  (i from RHS)++;
3.  (i from LHS)=temp;
The whole thing makes more sense.  
I did not realize that the third step was postponed until after the increment, and taken from a temp value. 

Thanks to you both for your help.